# hide the main download url

Tags: php, download

I have a problem and i don't know if there is a solution for that or not.

my problem is that i have got a download link like that :

```
http://remotewebsite.com/file.zip
```

the file is hosted on another website not mine.
and i would like the user to download the file without knowing the original url
like for example when user goes to my link

```
http://mywebsite.com/file.zip
```

it start downloading the file.

Think of it as if i were a tunnel between the website that hosts the file and the user.
Like for example each packet user requests from the remote website it will go through me and then it will be sent to the user.

I don't know if there is another easy way of doing that.

I am so sorry if it sound dumb but i really wish it could work.

Comment: It's possible to set up such a tunnel using Apache's proxying functions but you need root access to your server to set them up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just get the content of the file using `CURL` or `file_get_contents` and output it to the browser with the corresponding header deatils.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.zip');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
ob_clean();
flush();
echo file_get_contents("http://remotewebsite.com/file.zip");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but i am newbie to php i would love if you could give me a simple code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use URL Rewrite mechanism to route all requests to `file.zip` to a PHP script that would download the real file from the remote server and will serve it to your client.

If you specify the platform you work with (Apache / IIS), i can provide detailed example of how to achieve that.

For IIS 7 or later, use this in your `web.config` file:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="file.zip" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="file.zip" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="download_zip.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In `"download_zip.php"` use the PHP code "nauphal" contirbuted here.

Comment: i have a shared hosting Apache and IIS